# Add a shimmering animation on an image with alpha channel

Tags: swift, uikit, uiimageview, gradient

I'm trying to add a golden sheen on an `UIImageView` (variable named `assetImage`) to signify that it is something you can click on. This is the code that I'm using:

```
let shimmeringGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
shimmeringGradientLayer.frame = assetImage.bounds
shimmeringGradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0)
shimmeringGradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)
shimmeringGradientLayer.colors = [
    Constants.Shimmering.gradientColorOne,
    Constants.Shimmering.gradientColorTwo,
    Constants.Shimmering.gradientColorOne
]
shimmeringGradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 0.5, 1.0]
/* Adding the gradient layer on to the view */
assetImage.layer.addSublayer(shimmeringGradientLayer)

let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "shimmer")
animation.fromValue = [-1.0, -0.5, 0.0]
animation.toValue = [1.0, 1.5, 2.0]
animation.repeatCount = .infinity
animation.duration = 0.9
shimmeringGradientLayer.add(animation, forKey: animation.keyPath)
```

However, since the image that I'm using has alpha channels, the result looks like this:

[image]

But what I want is something more like this, where the gradient only shows on the parts of the `UIImageView` that *has* a non-transparent alpha. Note that this image isn't entirely clipped to the bounds of the image -- I'm not the best at using Figma!

[image]

Is this possible? I've tried adding the gradient layer as a mask of the `assetImage` instead of adding it as a sublayer (using the code below), but the gradient is no longer visible.

```
assetImage.layer.mask = shimmeringGradientLayer
```

Comment: Is the "cabinet" a separate imageView, and the cabinet image has transparent areas? Or, are you just trying to add a "gradient shimmer" to a portion of the full imageView?

Comment: Yeah the cabinet is a separate imageView with transparent areas. The frame of the cabinet's image view can be seen in the first image (the yellow area). I'm trying to have the gradient shimmer only apply to the non-transparent parts of the cabinet's image view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this by using the **same image** as a ***mask*** for the gradient layer.

I'll use this image (kinda, sorta, similar to yours):

[image]

and a clouds image for the "background" image.

Looks like this:

[image]

Nothing special... that's exactly what we expect.

Now, we'll add a gradient layer on the "cabinet" image view:

[image]

Again, just what we expect, but not what we ***want***.

So, we set the `.opacity` of the gradient layer to `0.5`:

[image]

Still not what we want, and you've already done all of that.

The "tricky" part comes next. We'll have subclassed `UIImageView` where we've added the gradient layer. Then:

```
// new CALayer
let cl = CALayer()
cl.frame = bounds
// set its contents to the image
cl.contents = image?.cgImage
// use it to mask the gradient layer
shimmeringGradientLayer.mask = cl
```

and it looks like this:

[image]

Now we can change the gradient colors and animate them to get a "golden sheen":

[image]

Here's a sample custom class:

```
class GradientMaskedImageView: UIImageView {
    
    // so we can toggle on/off
    public var isShimmering: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            doShimmer()
        }
    }
    
    // gradient colors: adjust as desired, or set from controller class
    public var gradColors: [UIColor] = [
        .yellow.withAlphaComponent(0.25),
        .yellow,
        .yellow.withAlphaComponent(0.25),
    ] {
        didSet {
            shimmeringGradientLayer.colors = gradColors.map({ $0.cgColor })
        }
    }
    
    private let shimmeringGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    
    convenience init() {
        self.init(frame: .zero)
    }
    override init(image: UIImage?) {
        super.init(image: image)
        commonInit()
    }
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    private func commonInit() -> Void {
        
        shimmeringGradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0)
        shimmeringGradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)
        shimmeringGradientLayer.colors = gradColors.map({ $0.cgColor })
        shimmeringGradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 0.5, 1.0]
        
        /* Adding the gradient layer on to the view */
        layer.addSublayer(shimmeringGradientLayer)
        
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        shimmeringGradientLayer.frame = bounds
        // we want to start with the gradient layer opacity at Zero
        shimmeringGradientLayer.opacity = 0.0
    }
    
    public func doShimmer() {
        
        if !isShimmering {
            
            // stop the animation and "hide" the gradient layer
            shimmeringGradientLayer.removeAllAnimations()
            shimmeringGradientLayer.opacity = 0.0
            
        } else {
            
            // we only need to setup the mask once
            if shimmeringGradientLayer.mask == nil {
                // new CALayer
                let cl = CALayer()
                cl.frame = bounds
                // set its contents to the image
                cl.contents = image?.cgImage
                // use it to mask the gradient layer
                shimmeringGradientLayer.mask = cl
            }
            
            let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "locations")
            animation.fromValue = [-1.0, -0.5, 0.0]
            animation.toValue = [1.0, 1.5, 2.0]
            animation.repeatCount = .infinity
            animation.duration = 0.9
            shimmeringGradientLayer.add(animation, forKey: animation.keyPath)
            
            // adjust as desired
            shimmeringGradientLayer.opacity = 0.5
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

and an example controller:

```
class ShimmerTestVC: UIViewController {
    
    let bkgImageView = UIImageView()
    
    let testView = GradientMaskedImageView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = .systemYellow
        
        guard let img = UIImage(named: "cabinet"),
              let bkImg = UIImage(named: "clouds")
        else {
            return
        }

        testView.image = img
        
        bkgImageView.image = bkImg

        bkgImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(bkgImageView)

        testView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(testView)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            bkgImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300.0),
            bkgImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bkgImageView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1.0),
            bkgImageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
            bkgImageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerYAnchor),

            // we want the custom view to have the same aspect ratio
            //  as the image we're using
            testView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200.0),
            testView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: testView.widthAnchor, multiplier: img.size.height / img.size.width),
            testView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
            testView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerYAnchor),
            
        ])

    }
    
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        testView.isShimmering.toggle()
    }
    
}
```

Tapping anywhere will toggle the "shimmer" on/off.